# How to skip empty and missing values from a migration

Tags: 8, migrations

I'm trying to skip fields that are not present in my source file or that are empty, but I keep getting "*Migration failed with source plugin exception: Passed variable is not an array or object*"

This is what I've tried in YML:

```
field_contact:
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: process
      source: contact_array
    -
      plugin: sub_process
      source: contact_array
      process:
        target_id:
          plugin: migration_lookup
          migration: import_contact_json
          source: Name
```

and

```
field_point_of_contact:
    plugin: sub_process
    source: contact_array
    process:
      target_id:
        -  
          plugin: skip_on_empty
          method: process
          source: name
        -
          plugin: migration_lookup
          migration: registry_import_pocs_json
          source: Name
```

Both of them have the same output (i.e. the error described above).

Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: the code for "skip_on_empty" process plugin is a bit strange. The condition is: if (!$value). I would expect to use isset() or empty()

Comment: `skip_on_empty` does a [PHP boolean evalutation](https://www.php.net/manual/types.comparisons.php). The name might be misleading from a PHP programmers point of view, but it is a quite sensible default in the context of migration sources (empty source string, different boolean representations,..)

Comment: I don't think skip_on_empty is your problem here. Try to debug your source fields with `process_dummy_field: | plugin: callback | callable: var_dump | source: my_source_field` (replace pipe with intented newline)

Comment: In some point your `contact_array` is not an array and as @Hudri said `skip_on_empty` will not prevent you from source passing down the wrong value to subprocess.

Comment: Another hint when you use multiple process plugins the source is passed down from each process to the next one, so you don't need to issue `source: my_source_field` each time, only for the first process in the chain. Also I see that you have a typo in your code can you confirm your source is `Name` or `name`?

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions! I'll keep trying and report back when I find a solution

Comment: Another thing, @Stefan are you 100% sure that the error comes from those lines? If you remove those your migration works? I mean migrate refers as `source plugin` the plugin responsible for fetching the data for your migration. Could you post your whole migration YAML?

Answer (score 1):

I have currently able resolve the issue with this work around.

**Combination One is source for paragraph value set 1.**

**Combination Two is source for paragraph value set 2.**

**field_section_two** is paragraph entity reference multi value field.

Migration Look Up Will return array in this format
[ 0 => , 1 => ] this will not considered as empty on skip_on_empty plugin , so passing array_filter plugin to skip the process to avoid exception.

```
combination_1:
    - 
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      source: image_1
      method: process
    -   
      plugin: migration_lookup
      migration: product_image_inset_one
      no_stub: true
      source:
        - ID
        - image_1
  combination_2:
    - 
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      source: image_2
      method: process
    - 
      plugin: migration_lookup
      migration: product_image_inset_two
      no_stub: true
      source:
        - ID
        - image_2
  field_section_two:
    - 
      plugin: callback
      callable: array_filter
      source:
        - '@combination_1'
        - '@combination_2'
    - 
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: process
    -
      plugin: sub_process
      source:
        - '@combination_1'
        - '@combination_2'
      process:
          target_id: '0'
          target_revision_id: '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to help without seeing the structure of your source file (at least 1 sample record). But, here are some pointers:

- At first glance, the error message says something about a *source plugin exception*. I believe the error might be stemming from the source plugin configuration.
- The approach you are taking with *skip on empty* seems to be in the correct direction.
- Depending on the data that the field contains, you might have to handle it differently. I usually add the following to debug exactly what is being received by a particular field process. Also, make sure that the value being sent to the `migrate_lookup` plugin is an array.

```
# ...
process:
  field_point_of_contact:
    - plugin: callback
      callable: print_r
      source: name
# ...
```

- Have you tried removing the *skip on empty* part? I don't remember correctly, but migrate lookup might be skipping empty values by itself.
- An array with empty strings is not considered *empty*. If your source provides values like `['']`, you might have to send the array through an `array_filter()` to remove empties.

I hope this helps. If it doesn't, you might want to share one row of fake data.

Answer (score 0):

I've promised I'll come back when this is solved, but it took a while :) Thank you everyone for helping out. It turned out the issue was the fact that "migration_dependencies" was set to "required", so any missing data in the source file was firing that exception. After hours of pulling my hair out, the fix was to change migration_dependencies to "optional" And no skip_on_empty is needed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Setting migration_dependencies to optional resolved this issue for me.  I was trying all the skips and custom processes only to realize my very simple error and resolution.